# assign a portion of a word to a variable

Tags: regex, linux, bash, terminal, grep

I am working on a bash script.

```
grep -R -l "image17" *
```

image17 will change to some other number when I go through my loop. When I execute the `grep` above, I get back the following:

```
slides/_rels/slide33.xml.rels
```

I need to put `slide33` in a variable because I want to use that to rename the file named `image17.jpeg` to be called `slide33.jpeg`. I need something to check for the above format and parse out starting at slide and ending with the numbers.

Another problem is the grep statement could come up with multiple results rather than one. I need a way to check to see how many results and if one do one thing and if more than one do another.

Here is what I have so far. Now I just need to put the grep as a variable and check to see how many times it happens and if it is one then do the regular expression to get the filename.

```
#!/bin/sh IFS=$'\n' 
where="/Users/mike/Desktop/test"
cd "${where}"
for file in $(find * -maxdepth 0 -type d)
do 
cd "${where}/${file}/images" 
ls -1 | grep -v ".png" | xargs -I {} rm -r "{}" 
cd "${where}/${file}/ppt" 
for images in $(find * -maxdepth 0 -type f) 
do 
if [ (grep -R -l "${images}" * | wc -l) == 1 ]
then
new_name=grep -R -l "slide[0-9]"
fi

done 
done
```

Comment: please post what you already have written, so we can help modify that

Comment: Mike, please click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6463144/edit) and repost your code with proper code formatting.  Then delete your comment... nobody is going to parse what you posted.

Comment: @MikePennington - I updated the post. What I have in there for the If statement and for new_name variable doesn't work but that is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 50 ]
  do
    grep -R -l "image${i}"
done
```

something like this might help

Or, to detect similar structured words you can do

```
grep -R -l "slide[0-9][0-9]"
```

or you can do

```
grep -R -l "slide[0-9]+"
```

to match atleast one digit and atmost any number

Check `man grep` for more in the "REGULAR EXPRESSION" section

this will match words starting with "slide" and ending with exactly two numbers

`grep -c` does count the number of matches, but does not print the matches. I think you should count the lines to detect the number of lines which `grep` matched and then execute the conditional statement.

Comment: thanks for that [0-9][0-9]. Not sure how many numbers it will be. If under 10 then it is a single digit. They shouldn't be in the triple digits.

Comment: check the edited answer. I would recommend you to have a look at the `grep` manual's regular expression section. This will really help you.